# Ruby on Rails: Encountered a syntax error while rendering template: check <nav class="navbar navbar-default">

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, navbar

I encountered this error while I was trying to do the part with 'accesing a current user'. I get the error on the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <%= link_to "Navbar", root_path, class="navbar-brand" %>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to "Acasa", root_path, class="nav-link" %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to "Medicamente", root_path, class="nav-link" %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to "Afectiuni", root_path, class="nav-link" %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to "Farmacii", root_path, class="nav-link" %>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <% if Current.user %>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <span><%= Current.user.email, class="nav-link" %></span>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= button_to "Deconectare", logout_path, method: :delete, class="nav-link" %>
        </li>
        <% else %>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to "Conectare", sign_in_path, class="nav-link" %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to "Inregistrare", sign_up_path, class="nav-link" %>
        </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
  
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

and ruby says that the problem is on the line 16(shared/navbar) from the code that is posted downside but I had no ideea what the problem should be here. Can you guys help me with some ideas about this error? I will apreciatte a lot. TY.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Myapp</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= render partial: "shared/navbar" %>

    <div class="container">
      <%= render partial: "shared/flash" %>
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a syntax error in your link it should be `class: "navbar-brand"` and not  `class="navbar-brand"`

`<%= link_to "Navbar", root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>`